# Why doesn't the expermintal molar solubility match the one calculated by the Ksp value?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility

For $\ce{HgCl2}$ ($M = \pu{271.52 g mol-1}$), the [reported](http://www.aqion.de/site/16) $K_\mathrm{sp}$ value is $10^{-15.69}$.

This means that the calculated molar solubility of $\ce{HgCl2}$ in water is $(10^{-15.69}/4)^{1/3}\cdot\pu{271.52 g mol-1} \approx \pu{0.0010 g L-1}$, or equivalently, $\pu{0.010 g cm-3}$.

However, in [Pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Mercuric-chloride#section=Solubility), the reported molar solubility is 6.9 g/100 cc. What is the source of the large deviation between the experimental and the theoretically calculated molar solubility of $\ce{HgCl2}$?

Comment: It does match, you're confusing HgCl2 - soluble and Hg2Cl2 - almost insoluble.

Comment: What do you mean. Both of my data values are for $\ce{HgCl2}$.

Comment: Just use, at very least, Wikipedia instead of some obscure and dubious sources.

Comment: @Mithoron bruh Wikipedia doesn't have Ksp data for it smh

Answer (score 1):

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{sp}$ value of $15.69$ for $\ce{HgCl2}$ given by [your reference](http://www.aqion.de/site/16) must have an error. First of all, $\ce{HgCl2}$ is fairly soluble in water at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table) lists it as $\pu{65.7 g L-1}$, yet lists solubility of $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$ as $\pu{3.25e-4 g L-1}$. Meantime, I found an [University of Arkansas, Little Rock website](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_Arkansas_Little_Rock/Chem_1403%3A_General_Chemistry_2/Text/17%3A_Aqueous_Equilibria/17-4%3A_Solubility_of_Salts), which has listed $K_\mathrm{sp}$ value of $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$ as $\pu{1.43e-18}$ ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{sp} = 17.84$).

The molar mass of $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$ is $\pu{472.09 g mol-1}$. Thus, theoretically, the solubility ($s$) of $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$ can be calculated similar way you did:

$$s = \left({\frac{\pu{1.43e-18 mol3 L-3}}{4}}\right)^{\frac13}\times \pu{472.09 g mol-1} = \pu{3.35e-4 g L-1}$$

I think this is close enough. :-)